# Make Flask's url_for use the 'https' scheme in an AWS load balancer without messing with SSLify

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, https, flask

I've recently added a SSL certificate to my webapp. It's deployed on Amazon Web Services uses load balancers. The load balancers work as reverse proxies, handling external HTTPS and sending internal HTTP. So all traffic to my Flask app is HTTP, not HTTPS, despite being a secure connection.

Because the site was already online before the HTTPS migration, I used [SSLify](https://github.com/kennethreitz/flask-sslify) to send `301 PERMANENT REDIRECTS` to HTTP connections. It works despite all connections being HTTP because the reverse proxy sets the `X-Forwarded-Proto` request header with the original protocol.

### The problem

`url_for` doesn't care about `X-Forwarded-Proto`. It will use the `my_flask_app.config['PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME']` when a scheme isn't available, but during a request a scheme is available. The HTTP scheme of the connection with the reverse proxy.

So when someone connects to `https://example.com`, it connects to the load balancer, which then connects to Flask using `http://example.com`. Flask sees the `http` and assumes the scheme is HTTP, not HTTPS as it originally was.

That isn't a problem in most `url_for` used in templates, but any `url_for` with `_external=True` will use http instead of https. Personally, I use `_external=True` for `rel=canonical` since I heard it was recommended practice. Besides that, using `Flask.redirect` will prepend non-_external urls with `http://example.com`, since the redirect header must be a fully qualified URL.

If you redirect on a form post for example, this is what would happen.

1. Client posts `https://example.com/form`
2. Server issues a `303 SEE OTHER` to `http://example.com/form-posted`
3. SSLify then issues a `301 PERMANENT REDIRECT` to `https://example.com/form-posted`

Every redirect becomes 2 redirects because of SSLify.

### Attempted solutions

#### Adding PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME config

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26636880/1660459

```
my_flask_app.config['PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME'] = 'https'
```

Doesn't work because there is a scheme during a request, and that one is used instead. See https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/1129#issuecomment-51759359

#### Wrapping a middleware to mock HTTPS

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28247577/1660459

```
def _force_https(app):
    def wrapper(environ, start_response):
        environ['wsgi.url_scheme'] = 'https'
        return app(environ, start_response)
    return wrapper
app = Flask(...)
app = _force_https(app)
```

As is, this didn't work because I needed that app later. So I used [wsgi_app](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.wsgi_app) instead.

```
def _force_https(wsgi_app):
    def wrapper(environ, start_response):
        environ['wsgi.url_scheme'] = 'https'
        return wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
    return wrapper
app = Flask(...)
app.wsgi_app = _force_https(app.wsgi_app)
```

Because `wsgi_app` is called before any `app.before_request` handlers, doing this makes SSLify think the app is already behind a secure request and then it won't do any HTTP-to-HTTPS redirects.

#### Patching url_for

(I can't even find where I got this one from)

```
from functools import partial
import Flask
Flask.url_for = partial(Flask.url_for, _scheme='https')
```

This could work, but Flask will give an error if you set `_scheme` but not `_external`. Since most of my app `url_for` are internal, it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 28):

I was having these same issues with `redirect(url_for('URL'))' behind an AWS Elastic Load Balancer recently & I solved it this using the [werkzeug.contrib.fixers.ProxyFix](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/middleware/proxy_fix/)
call in my code.
example:

```
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix
app = Flask(__name__)

app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
```

The `ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)` adds HTTP proxy support to an application that was not designed with HTTP proxies in mind. It sets REMOTE_ADDR, HTTP_HOST from X-Forwarded headers.

Example:

```
from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix
# App is behind one proxy that sets the -For and -Host headers.
app = ProxyFix(app, x_for=1, x_host=1)
```

Comment: This is **the** fix. Thank you so much!

Comment: This is a super hero.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fix! Use it with AWS ELB and EC2 instances as targets

Comment: Since werkzeug 0.15 (https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/middleware/proxy_fix/) it should be `from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix; app = ProxyFix(app, x_for=1, x_host=1, x_proto=1, x_port=1)` - the class was moved to `midleware` package and it is neccessary to set `x_...` parameters to make it actually use the headers (x_host for X-Forwarded-Host and so on for other expected headers).

Comment: According to AWS documentation (
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/x-forwarded-headers.html) only these headers are set: `X-Forwarded-For`, `X-Forwarded-Proto`, `X-Forwarded-Port`. Do not set x_host as trusted.

Also, the python path has changed to `from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix`.

Please update to for Flask apps: `app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app, x_for=1, x_proto=1, x_port=1)`.

Comment: Since `X-Forwarded-Host` is not set by AWS ALB, then set manually using: `SERVER_NAME` to ensure that `url_for` correctly resolves. This may also require you to add an entry in `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 8):

Digging around Flask source code, I found out that `url_for` uses the `Flask._request_ctx_stack.top.url_adapter` when there is a request context.

The `url_adapter.scheme` defines the scheme used. To make the `_scheme` parameter work, `url_for` will swap the `url_adapter.scheme` temporarily and then set it back before the function returns.

(this behavior has been discussed on github as to whether it should be the previous value or PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME)

Basically, what I did was set `url_adapter.scheme` to https with a before_request handler. This way doesn't mess with the request itself, only with the thing generating the urls.

```
def _force_https():
    # my local dev is set on debug, but on AWS it's not (obviously)
    # I don't need HTTPS on local, change this to whatever condition you want.
    if not app.debug: 
        from flask import _request_ctx_stack
        if _request_ctx_stack is not None:
            reqctx = _request_ctx_stack.top
            reqctx.url_adapter.url_scheme = 'https'

app.before_request(_force_https)
```

Comment: For anyone coming here lately, this does not work with Flask 2.1 at least, and in 2.2 the `_request_ctx_stack` is going away. In my testing, the `Request` object is already instantiated with a `scheme` property by the time it is present in `before_request`, therefore you can change the `url_adapter` but it doesn't affect the request in progress. For the Flask changes I mentioned: See 2.2 docs https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/reqcontext/#how-the-context-works vs 2.1 https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/reqcontext/#how-the-context-works