# flask oidc auth callback redirects to http instead of https

Tags: nginx, flask, plotly-dash, okta, flask-oidc

This is my first attempt to deploy a plotly dash python web app. I followed below tutorials to get going

- [digital ocean flask app with gunicorn and nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04)
- [Okta authentication for flask app using OpenIdConnect](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/07/12/flask-tutorial-simple-user-registration-and-login)

The app runs fine on an ec2 instance with nginx and gunicorn all in docker containers. The redirect to okta for authentication and back works fine (using ec2 instance public ip)

After setting redirect for domain name via aws load balancer (HTTPS) it started failing complaining **404** as url scheme returned was **http** instead of **https**.

First i added `OVERWRITE_REDIRECT_URI` config with **https** which fixed incorrect redirect uri problem on okta side

Then tried `ProxyFix` and all options in below SO posts but after redirect to */authorization-code/callback?code=<long code value>*, the response always comes back with **http://***<my_website_name>/<page>* instead of **https**

1. [Make Flask's url_for use the 'https' scheme in an AWS load balancer without messing with SSLify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34802316/make-flasks-url-for-use-the-https-scheme-in-an-aws-load-balancer-without-mess?noredirect=1&lq=1)
2. [X-Forwarded-Proto and Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23347387/x-forwarded-proto-and-flask?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I'm stuck at this point, what am i missing here?

Thanks

*nginx conf.d/conf*

```
upstream app_server {
    server dash:8050;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
        gzip_static on;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Having a similar issue..