# oauth2client.flask_util redirect_uri in http instead of https

Tags: python-2.7, flask, app-engine-flexible, oauth2client

I know `oauth2client` is deprecated but still, that's the one we use.
When I start the oauth2 process with Google, it always tries to redirect me to the HTTP version of my app.

I've seen the `url_for` method of Flask is supposed to be based on the request context and when I start the process (i.e. calling the `oauth2authorize` url), I am in HTTPS. So I don't understand why it passes a `redirect_uri` in HTTP...

This is the code of Flask

```
flow = client.OAuth2WebServerFlow(
            client_id=self.client_id,
            client_secret=self.client_secret,
            scope=scopes,
            state=state,
            redirect_uri=url_for('oauth2.callback', _external=True),
            **kw)
```

My app runs in App Engine flexible, if that helps. And I also tried to set the `PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME` of my Flask app to 'https'.

And in case that wasn't clear: I don't want the redirect_uri to be HTTP, my app is supposed to be HTTPS only ;-)

Comment: Can you confirm that `print(url_for('oauth2.callback', _external=True))` gives you an https scheme? Also, do you have the https url in the authorised redirect uris in your Google OAuth setup?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it might be coming from the [url_for method](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.url_for) when using the `_external=True` that generates the absolute URL for the callback. This absolute URL may be getting a value of HTTP instead of HTTPS.

When using this `_external=True` you can add `_scheme='https'` which will force the generated URL to be HTTPS only. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15111968/11641073) an answer to a related question where they refer to this same error.

Comment: Hello, There is no `handlers` section and so no `secure:always` in App Engine Flexible I'm afraid (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml)

Comment: True, I am sorry I totally missed that you were using flex, will edit the answer now!