# How to return location header url with protocol https?

Tags: flask, https

I have a secured webapp with a flask based Web and Celery containers that communicates via **https**.
The Web container receives a POST fetch, with https protocol, from the client, starts a background task, and returns a response that includes the url for the task status:

```
jsonify({}), 202, {'Location': url_for('create_zip_file_taskstatus', task_id=task.id)}
```

The client waits for the response and then gets the url for the task status:

```
let create_zipfile_status_url = response.headers.get('location');
```

The relative url of the location itself without the protocol is fine:

```
url_for('create_zip_file_taskstatus', task_id=task.id): /status/c4bc9e2c-6ecd-4bf3-bc25-782f8e4e66c6
```

But the full url has a protocol of **http**, which causes CORS errors.

```
create_zipfile_status_url: http://localhost/status/7aba0d27-712d-4623-a37e-5262b53fe212
```

**How can I set the location header url to be with protocol https (instead of http)?**

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810795/flask-url-for-generating-http-url-instead-of-https).
Needed to add `_external=True, _scheme='https'` i.e. change from

```
return jsonify({}), 202, {'Location': url_for('create_zip_file_taskstatus', task_id=task.id)}
```

to

```
return jsonify({}), 202, {'Location': url_for('create_zip_file_taskstatus', task_id=task.id, _external=True, _scheme='https')}
```