# Flask in production with Caddy and Waitress url_for redirect to localhost

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, caddy, waitress

I have a Flask server running on a Windows EC2 instance.

I need to have it using **https** protocol, so my setup is like this :

- I have a Caddy server
- I use Waitress to run my flask app

Here is my config for Caddy :

```
example.com:443{
    proxy / 127.0.0.1:8080
    tls me@example.com
}
```

Everything is working fine excepted that in my **application.py** file, when I do :

```
return redirect(url_for('test', filename=filename))
```

My web browser redirect me :

- from : **https://example.com/**
- to : **http://127.0.0.1/test/my_filename**

Same result with `_external=True`

But on a template page, for example **https://example.com/test2** rendered using `render_template( "test2.html")` if I have a link `<a href="{{ url_for('index') }}" />` the HTML generated is well : **https://example.com/**

For now I have hard coded my url in application.py but this is not the way that I would like to keep it...

Comment: did you try: _scheme="https" in url_for ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have updated my Caddyfile to this and now it's working great !

```
example.com:443 {
    proxy / 127.0.0.1:8080 { 
        header_upstream Host {host} 
        header_upstream X-Real-IP {remote} 
        header_upstream X-Forwarded-For {remote} 
        websocket 
    }
        tls me@example.com
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45693122/1805275) gave me a hint.

[This answer](https://github.com/caddyserver/caddy/issues/1640#issuecomment-298490969) helped me build the Caddyfile.