# Azure Enterprise SAML App changing my RelayState URL from HTTPS to HTTP (sometimes)?

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, saml

I've found various questions here on Azure and SAML RelayState stuff but I haven't found anything specifically on my particular issue. Here are the details:

1. I have an Azure Enterprise SAML app
2. I have set the RelayState (and
   all other) SAML URLs to be **HTTPS** (not *HTTP*)
3. The app and related authentication mechanics all work fine when the *HTTP* issue doesn't occur
4. **However sometimes** when I logon and test the app Azure uses a *HTTP* URL for the RelayState instead of HTTPS**
5. *Screenshots below show the details/crux of the issue - text edited for security/clarity.*

**I've noticed the issue doesn't *always* happen on all devices/situations (Chrome on PC for example) - but the issue DOES always seem to occur on: Android device, iOS device or Safari OSX.

Things I've tried to resolve:

- Have tried: Uploading a fresh IDP metadata xml into my SP and uploading a fresh SP metadata xml into my (Azure) IDP - but the issue remains.
- Have tried: Changing my RelayState URL to something way different - and Azure seems to ignore this change entirely.
- Have not yet tried: Recreating the entire IDP/Azure app (would love to avoid that).

I have worked around the issue for now by getting the related server(s) to use auto HTTP to HTTPS redirection but I would really like to know why Azure is behaving like this and how to resolve the core issue if possible.

**Does anyone know what in the world is going on? Why, in this day and age, would Azure or anything else be forcing *HTTP* instead of HTTPS after an Enterprise SAML app authentication?** Thanks in advance for any suggestions/etc anyone might have.

[image]

Related (but not the same issue/question):

- [Azure Ad login redirect url is http instead of https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71162813/azure-ad-login-redirect-url-is-http-instead-of-https)
- [Flask app absolute url redirecting in http instead of https in azure app services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60662495/flask-app-absolute-url-redirecting-in-http-instead-of-https-in-azure-app-service)

Comment: is the remote end redirecting from HTTPS to HTTP rather than Azure changing it?

Comment: Is this IDP initiated or SP initiated flow? I'm confused because you're entering URL into relay state in Azure which makes me think it's IDP initiated, but what's the point of that URL then? Also, it would be helpful to see SAML request and response, depending on your flow. If you set relay state on request you'll receive the same one on response, so maybe that's why?

Comment: Sorry this is SP initiated. To be honest I don't have an advanced grasp on the details of how SP-initiated vs IDP-initiated works. My setup is basically: 1) SP sends user to IDP, 2) IDP authenticates and 3) IDP returns user to SP. But in #3 the IDP is sending the user incorrectly to HTTP instead of HTTPS (even though all URLs in the IDP setup are HTTPS)